# Pipeline job fails because of risky phpUnit tests and depracations

Tags: gitlab, phpunit, pipeline, cicd

I have a pipeline that executes phpUnit tests, there's no failures running the tests but there's few tests that are risky or incomplete and there's few deprecation notices which make my pipeline fail. Is there a way to make the job not fail because of these warnings and only fail on phpUnit test failure?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled" />`

Puting this line inside my `phpunit.xml` file disabled deprecation warnings and the job was successful.